# How to introduce a new existential condition from a witness in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

My question relates to how to construct an `exist` term in the set of conditions/hypotheses.

I have the following intermediate proof state:

```
X : Type
P : X -> Prop
H : (exists x : X, P x -> False) -> False
x : X
H0 : P x -> False
______________________________________(1/1)
P x
```

In my mind, I know that because of `H0`, `x` is a witness for `(exists x : X, P x -> False)`, and I want to introduce a name:

```
w: (exists x : X, P x -> False)
```

based on the above reasoning and then use it with `apply H in w` to generate a `False` in the hypothesis, and finally `inversion` the `False`.

But I don't know what tactic/syntax to use to introduce the witness `w` above. The best I can reach so far is that `Check (ex_intro _ (fun x => P x -> False)  x H0)).` gives `False`.

Can someone explain how to introduce the existential condition, or an alternative way to finish the proof?

Thanks.

P.S. What I have for the whole theorem to prove is:

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
Proof.
  unfold excluded_middle. unfold not. 
  intros exm X P H x.

  destruct (exm (P x)).
    apply H0.
    Check (H (ex_intro _ (fun x => P x -> False)  x H0)).
```

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to `unfold` `excluded_middle` or `not` to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, since you already know how to construct a term of type `False`, you can add it to the context using `pose proof`. This gives:

```
pose proof (H (ex_intro (fun x => P x -> False)  x H0))
```

You can even directly destruct the term, which solves the goal.

```
destruct (H (ex_intro (fun x => P x -> False)  x H0))
```

Another way to finish your proof is to prove `False`. You can change the goal to `False` with tactics like `exfalso` or `contradiction`. With this approach, you can use hypotheses of the form `_ -> False` that are otherwise difficult to manipulate. For your proof, you can write:

```
exfalso. apply H. (* or directly, contradiction H *)
exists x. assumption.
```

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting because I tried `induction (H (ex_intro _ (fun x => P x -> False)  x H0))`, but it didn't work. Could you explain why `destruct` worked here instead?

Comment: Actually, it works for me. Maybe it is due to the underscore you are using. `ex_intro` expects 4 parameters, but the first one is implicit, so it is not needed to specify it. I will edit my answer. But I do not understand why it passes type-checking for you.

Comment: My fault, I tried `inversion` (not `induction`) trying to `inversion` the `False`. But it didn't work. Do you know why `destruct`/`induction` works while `inversion` doesn't?

Comment: It also works for me. After `pose proof (H (ex_intro (fun x => P x -> False) x H0))`, `inversion H1` solves the goal. What did you try to inverse ? Note that you must invert the hypothesis of type `False`, not `False` itself.

Comment: thanks. I probably inversed False rather than its evidence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `assert` tactic:

```
assert(w: exists x, P x -> False).
```

It will ask you to prove this statement in a new sub-goal, and will add `w` to your existing goal. For this kind of trivial proof, you can inline the proof directly:

```
assert(w: exists x, P x -> False) by (exists x; exact H0).
```